# Can I put an 'object' interface on an Array in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

For showing a line on a map I get many data with coordinates from a REST service:

```
{
  "name": "line1"
  "route": [["2015-03-26T23:29:57",-0.9,-81.8],["2015-03-26T23:34:58",-0.9,-81.8],["2015-03-26T23:39:59",-0.8,-81.8],...]
}
```

Because of the many data in JSON I am using an array (with Timestamp, Latitude, Longitude), instead of an object, because then I would have double the size of the response (because of repeating the property names).

I have an interface:

```
export interface ILine {
    name: string
    route: IWaypoint[]
}
```

Now I would like to call:

```
public handleResponse(line: ILine) {
    for (var i in line.route) {
        var waypoint = line.route[i];
        var timestamp: string = waypoint.timestamp;
        var lat: number = waypoint.latitude;
        var lon: number = waypoint.longitude;
    }
}
```

But is that possible? How should I implement the interface IWaypoint?

This works for type-safety, but I still can not use property names:

```
  export interface IWaypoint extends Array<Date | number> {
    0: Date
    1: number
    2: number
  }
```

I still have to remember that the latitude is on position 1.

When using 'constants' (var or enum) for the index, Typescript is not able to determine the type.

```
const wpLatitude = 1;
var lat: number = waypoint[wpLatitude]; // <- error: Argument of type 'number | Date' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'

enum WaypointIndex {
  TIMESTAMP,
  LATITUDE,
  LONGITUDE
}

var lat: number = waypoint[WaypointIndex.LATITUDE]; // <- error
```

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript tries not to [modify ouput JS](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9) most of the time, so if you want to access named fields on an array, your best bet is to convert it to an object:

```
var route = line.route.map((wp) =>
{
    return { timestamp: wp[0], latitude: wp[1], longitude: wp[2] };
});
```